# How to import a large database using .sql file in MySQL (Wampserver)?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have an exported database file (`.sql`) file which is almost 5GB. I want to import it into MySQL using PhpMyAdmin.

First, I created a database with any name and then using the "Import" wizard, I chose the `.sql` file but I got the upload size error.

To solve this, I edited the php.ini file of the Wampserver like below:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 5G
```

It is worth mentioning that my `.sql` database file is smaller than 5GB and that is why I have set the `upload_max_filesize` to `5G`

The problem was not solved after this step and beside the upload file size error, sometimes, I get:

> phpMyAdmin - Error Incorrect format parameter

How can I import this database file? I also have `.frm`, `.MYD` and `.MYI` files.

Comment: Go to console (windows -> cmd), log in mysql and import ***.sql file, i never export or import via phpmyadmin

Comment: Do not try to import a 5GB file through phpmyadmin, it was not designed for this!

Comment: https://ideaofinnovation.blogspot.com/2020/10/import-mysql-dump-file-using-mysql.html

Comment: Do not do this! I guarantee you will run into RAM limits, timeout errors, corrupted partial-imports, PMA is _NOT_ suitable for large imports. Instead use MySQL Workbench or DBeaver or the cli mysql client, these are designed to be able to handle large imports, PMA is not.

Answer (score -1):

Under WAMP->MySQL->my.ini

```
max_allowed_packet = 800M
read_buffer_size = 2014K
```

Under WAMP->PHP->PHP.ini

```
max_input_time = 20000
memory_limit = 128M
```

it works for me you can check for yourself

Comment: Http request-response cycle was not designed to run for hours.